# (py)mongo BulkUpdate element in array based on filter

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to create many update operations for bulk updates.

I am trying to select an element (dictionary) in an array by `array filter`, but update (or more precisely upsert) another field (in the bellow example `new_field`) on the element than the field the array filter is applied to.

**So in short:**

- Have Array of dictionaries
- Select element in the array by key_1
- Upsert key_2:value_2 on previously selected element

---

I am currently trying to get this working with one (test)record.

the (test)record looks like this:

```
{
  '_id': '001d1a70fdc77812053d',
  'images': {
    'photos': [{'id':'jxptm90a'}]
  },
  ...
}
```

the update operation looks like this:

```
update_operation = pymongo.UpdateOne(
    filter={'_id': '001d1a70fdc77812053d'},
    update={
        '$currentDate': {'oplog_skip': True},
        '$set': { "images.photos.$[new_field]": 2 },

    },
    upsert=False,
    array_filters=[ { 'id': 'jxptm90a' }]
)
```

however, executing the command like this:

```
  db.collection.bulk_write([update_operation])
```

results in the following error:

```
{'writeErrors': [{'index': 0, 'code': 2, 'errmsg': "No array filter found for identifier 'test' in path 'images.photos.$[test]'", 'op': SON([('q', {'_id': '001d1a70fdc77812053d'}), ('u', {'$currentDate': {'oplog_skip': True}, '$set': {'images.photos.$[test]': 2}}), ('multi', False), ('upsert', False), ('arrayFilters', [{'id': 'jxptm90a'}])])}], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 0, 'nModified': 0, 'nRemoved': 0, 'upserted': []}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BulkWriteError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-d31fe774222f> in <module>
      5 
      6     try:
----> 7         db.collection.bulk_write([update])
      8     except _pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as bwe:
      9         print(bwe.details)

~/anaconda3/envs/py363/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in bulk_write(self, requests, ordered, bypass_document_validation, session)
    495 
    496         write_concern = self._write_concern_for(session)
--> 497         bulk_api_result = blk.execute(write_concern, session)
    498         if bulk_api_result is not None:
    499             return BulkWriteResult(bulk_api_result, True)

~/anaconda3/envs/py363/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py in execute(self, write_concern, session)
    511                 self.execute_no_results(sock_info, generator)
    512         else:
--> 513             return self.execute_command(generator, write_concern, session)
    514 
    515 

~/anaconda3/envs/py363/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py in execute_command(self, generator, write_concern, session)
    339 
    340         if full_result["writeErrors"] or full_result["writeConcernErrors"]:
--> 341             _raise_bulk_write_error(full_result)
    342         return full_result
    343 

~/anaconda3/envs/py363/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py in _raise_bulk_write_error(full_result)
    138         full_result["writeErrors"].sort(
    139             key=lambda error: error["index"])
--> 140     raise BulkWriteError(full_result)
    141 
    142 

BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter identifier must match the $set operation; e.g. something like:

```
update_operation = pymongo.UpdateOne(
    filter={'_id': '001d1a70fdc77812053d'},
    update={
        '$currentDate': {'oplog_skip': True},
        '$set': { "images.photos.$[id]": 2 },
    },
    upsert=False,
    array_filters=[ { 'id': 'jxptm90a' }]
)
```